# How to add localserver to existing project in webpack?

Tags: firebase, webpack, mithril.js

I use a starter for Mithril.js that run well ([starter on github](https://github.com/talyaron/mithril-starter)). To run the app, I write in the CLI: "npm start".

After adding to my project Firebase, the app needs localserver. I tryed many other starters and all failed in a second run or in first run.

I try to use [local-web-server](https://github.com/lwsjs/local-web-server) in webpack (package.json) in the following way:

```
"start": "webpack -d --watch ws --spa public/index.html",
```

but it gives error.

How can I add to the starter web-server?

Answer (score 0):

try installing 
npm install webpack-dev-server --save-dev

add this setting to webpack.config.js

```
devServer: {
  contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
  compress: true,
  port: 9000
}
```

and contentBase  add your file path

Comment: This is the config:
devServer: {
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "public/index.html"),
        compress: true,
        port: 9000
    }

I used 'http://localhost:9000/' and got error: failed to connect

Comment: `code`                                                                                                 var config = {
  apiKey: "<API_KEY>",
  authDomain: "<PROJECT_ID>.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com",
  storageBucket: "<BUCKET>.appspot.com",
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);